# Spring aop expression

Tags: java, spring, aop

This is **applicationContext.xml** AOP part:

```
<bean id="logHandler" class="demo.anderson.aop.LogHandler"></bean>
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="log" ref="logHandler">    
        <aop:pointcut id="addLog" expression="execution(* demo.anderson.controller.StudentController.*(..)) || execution(* demo.anderson.controller.ScoreController.*(..))"  />
        <aop:before method="beforeLog" pointcut-ref="addLog" />
        <aop:after method="afterLog" pointcut-ref="addLog" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

It's working!

But when I configure aop:pointcut like this:

```
<aop:pointcut id="addLog" expression="execution(* demo.anderson.controller.*.*(..))"  />
```

It's broken:

> 18-Jul-2017 11:06:39.416 嚴重 [http-nio-8090-exec-71]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception
>   sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected raw type form of
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$Match
>   ............................................................. Caused
>   by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected raw type form of
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$Match
>   .............................................................
>
> 18-Jul-2017 11:06:39.434 資訊 [http-nio-8090-exec-71]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root
>   WebApplicationContext

Can somebody tell me why? What's the correct configuration?

Answer (score 0):

```
<aop:pointcut id="addLog" expression="execution(* demo.anderson.controller..*.*(..))"  />
```

refered from spring docs.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

The execution of any method defined in the service package or a sub-package:

execution(* com.xyz.service..`*`.`*`(..))

Comment: Thx for answering, but it's the same,there's no sub-package in the controller package.
Any other advice?